# Why are KeyEvents Only Generated for the Last Key Pressed?

Tags: javafx-8

I'm testing key handlers, and I ran into a problem.

In its barest form, I have the following code:

```
mainScene.setOnKeyPressed( event -> {
    System.out.println("Handler called for: " + event.getCode());
});
```

As expected, when a key is pressed, it prints out the associated code.

The problem is, if I hold 2 keys at once, only the last key pressed generates constant events. I want to be able to add pressed keys to a queue to be dealt with elsewhere, but only the last key pressed will be added to the queue.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

The only workaround I could find was to use a map to record codes, and set up a separate pressed and released handler to add/remove codes from the map. This works, but requires constant polling of every key I may need to react to, instead of being able to just check if the pressed-key queue is empty.

Comment: Use it how? As I mentioned, I do have a way of using `setOfRelease`, but it involves constant polling of an object that tracks key presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the JVM is receiving the key pressed event from the operating system, so the repeat-key behavior when you hold two keys down is determined at the OS level.

To manage your own key press repeats, you can use a timeline with an indefinite cycle count; start the timeline when the key is pressed and stop it when the key is released. You will probably need to manage these in a `Map<KeyCode, Timeline>` to handle multiple keys. Have the timelines call a method and pass the key code for central handling of the key presses: this will avoid the need for polling.

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class MultiRepeatKey extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(), 400, 400);


        Map<KeyCode, Timeline> keyRepeats = new HashMap<>();
        Duration keyPressDelay = Duration.millis(200);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (! keyRepeats.containsKey(e.getCode())) {
                Timeline repeat = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, event -> processKey(e.getCode())),
                        new KeyFrame(keyPressDelay));
                repeat.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                repeat.play();
                keyRepeats.put(e.getCode(), repeat);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (keyRepeats.containsKey(e.getCode())) {
                Timeline repeat = keyRepeats.get(e.getCode());
                repeat.stop();
                keyRepeats.remove(e.getCode());
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void processKey(KeyCode code) {
        System.out.println(code.getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, another option that may make sense for you is to just keep a `Map` from keys to some representation of the functionality you want, and then to keep a `Set` of the implementations of those functionality. Then use an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html) to update the UI depending on which keys are pressed. (An `AnimationTimer`executes its `handle` method on each frame rendering; the parameter passed in is a timestamp in nanoseconds.).

Obviously if you had many mappings, you would define the mappings elsewhere, but here is the idea:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.DoubleFunction;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MultiRepeatKey extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 50, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);

        Pane pane = new Pane(rect);

        Set<DoubleFunction<Point2D>> motions = new HashSet<>();
        Map<KeyCode, DoubleFunction<Point2D>> keyMappings = new HashMap<>();
        keyMappings.put(KeyCode.UP, delta -> new Point2D(0, -delta));
        keyMappings.put(KeyCode.DOWN, delta -> new Point2D(0, delta));
        keyMappings.put(KeyCode.LEFT, delta -> new Point2D(-delta, 0));
        keyMappings.put(KeyCode.RIGHT, delta -> new Point2D(delta, 0));

        double speed = 150.0 ; // pixels / second

        AnimationTimer anim = new AnimationTimer() {

            private long lastUpdate = 0 ;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                if (lastUpdate > 0) {

                    double elapsedSeconds = (now - lastUpdate) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                    double delta = speed * elapsedSeconds ;

                    Point2D loc = motions.stream()
                            .map(m -> m.apply(delta))
                            .reduce(new Point2D(rect.getX(), rect.getY()), Point2D::add);
                    loc = clamp(loc, 0, 0, pane.getWidth() - rect.getWidth(), pane.getHeight() - rect.getHeight());        

                    rect.setX(loc.getX());
                    rect.setY(loc.getY());
                }

                lastUpdate = now ;
            }
        };
        anim.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> motions.add(keyMappings.get(e.getCode())));
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> motions.remove(keyMappings.get(e.getCode())));


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Point2D clamp(Point2D p, double minX, double minY, double maxX, double maxY) {
        if (p.getX() < minX) {
            p = new Point2D(minX, p.getY());
        } else if (p.getX() > maxX) {
            p = new Point2D(maxX, p.getY());
        }
        if (p.getY() < minY) {
            p = new Point2D(p.getX(), minY);
        } else if (p.getY() > maxY) {
            p = new Point2D(p.getX(), maxY);
        }
        return p ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example is nearly exactly what I have now. I was trying to avoid the constant polling of `downKeys`, especially once I'm needing to react to more than just 4 keys; although that may be a premature worry.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: Say I have 20 keys that need to be polled every frame, and I'm running 60 fps. That doesn't seem very efficient given 90% of the keys will rarely be pressed. That's why I wanted to just queue pressed keys, so the only check that needs to be done each frame is a check of the size of the queue.

Comment: It's easy enough to refactor around that, though, isn't it? See update for an example.